# Valve connected to Hunter Node not opening

Tags: sprinkler-system

I've got a Hunter Node that operates a single zone in my yard. After "dewinterizing" the system, noticed that this zone was not operating.

The valve looked a bit old, so just replaced the valve top and internals (it's a Hunter PGV valve). Still no dice.
I realized the valve came with an A/C solenoid, so switched it to a DC just to be sure since it's a Node DC operated zone. Still doesn't work.

Zone has water and if I manually turn the solenoid the zone comes on, which leads me to believe the valve is OK. When I trigger the solenoid by turning on the zone, I can hear it click, so I believe the solenoid to be operating and the Node has plenty of battery life left.

So...any ideas? Only thing I can think to do is take the valve top off again and make sure nothing looks amiss